# Holomorphic Morse functions

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables, morse-theory

For a holomorphic $f:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $a=(a_1, \dots, a_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n$, let $f_a:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be  the function 
$$(z_1, \dots, z_n) \mapsto a_1z_1 + \dots + a_nz_n + f$$

For general $a$, does $f_a$ have only nondegenerate critical points?

(Nondegeneracy is defined here in terms of the holomorphic Hessian bilinear form.)

Answer (score 1):

This is true (at least locally) if $g=\text{grad}(f)$ has isolated zeros. A proof can be found in Appendix B of Milnor's "Singular points of complex hypersurfaces".

The idea is to relate the rank of the Jacobian of $g$ (=Hessian of $f$) to the local degree of the mapping  $g: \mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n$.